# Unwanted Added Spacing to Each <li>

Tags: jquery, css, express, for-loop

I've looked for the issue, but I can't see it. Somewhere in this code space is being added to each list item. I think it's in the for loop because it adds the same amount of space each time.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    $(function(){
  $.get('/frameworks', appendToList);

  //POST request
  $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var frameworkData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/frameworks',
      data: frameworkData
    }).done(function(frameworkName) {
      frameworkName = frameworkName[0].toUpperCase() + frameworkName.slice(1).toLowerCase();
      appendToList([frameworkName]);
      form.trigger('reset');
    });
  });

  //Del event

  function appendToList(frameworks) {
    var list = [];
    for(var i in frameworks) {
      framework = frameworks[i];
      content = '<a href="/frameworks/' +framework+'">' +framework+ '</a>' + '<a href="#" data-framework="' +framework+ '"><img src="del.png"></a>';
      list.push($('<li>', { html: content }));
    }
    $('.frameworks-list').append(list);
    console.log(list);
  }

});
```

What am I missing?

Here's the resultant HTML:

```
<ul class="frameworks-list">
  <li>
    <a href="/frameworks/React">React</a>
    <a href="#" data-framework="React"><img src="del.png"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/frameworks/Express">Express</a>
    <a href="#" data-framework="Express"><img src="del.png"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/frameworks/Angular">Angular</a>
    <a href="#" data-framework="Angular"><img src="del.png"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So it looks like the li is closing. I tried adding this line:

```
list.push($('<li>', { html: content }), '</li>'); //--------THIS LINE----------
```

But it didn't work.

I just remembered that when I take out the image like so:

```
content = '<a href="/frameworks/' +framework+'">' +framework+ '</a>' + '<a href="#" data-framework="' +framework+ '"><span>X</span></a>';
```

I get this:

[image]

So there's an issue with the image.

Comment: Can you show the resultant html markup?

Answer (score 1):

It might be too obvious, but have you tried changing the padding and/or margin with css?

Comment: I thought that, but excess padding doesn't show in the Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing `</li>`.

Some browsers, such as Google Chrome, interpret this code:

```
<li>Hi1
<li>Hi1
<li>Hi1
```

As:

```
<li>Hi1
 <li>Hi1
    <li>Hi1</li>
  </li>
</li>
```

You need to change your code to:

```
$(function(){
  $.get('/frameworks', appendToList);

  //POST request
  $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var frameworkData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/frameworks',
      data: frameworkData
    }).done(function(frameworkName) {
      frameworkName = frameworkName[0].toUpperCase() + frameworkName.slice(1).toLowerCase();
      appendToList([frameworkName]);
      form.trigger('reset');
    });
  });

  //Del event

  function appendToList(frameworks) {
    var list = [];
    for(var i in frameworks) {
      framework = frameworks[i];
      content = '<a href="/frameworks/' +framework+'">' +framework+ '</a>' + '<a href="#" data-framework="' +framework+ '"><img src="del.png"></a>';
      list.push($('<li>', { html: content }), '</li>'); //--------THIS LINE----------
    }
    $('.frameworks-list').append(list);
    console.log(list);
  }

});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I'm going to check out jQuery's docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not closing the `<li` in here:

```
list.push($('<li>', { html: content }));
```

Comment: I think there is something to this. I'm going to look into jQuery's docs to see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

@anivdwerf was right about it being a CSS issue, but I wanted to give an in-depth answer. Floating it to the left for some reason caused it to add the additional spacing. I'm still not sure as to why, but I just added the image to the left in JavaScript code like so:

```
  content = '<a href="#" data-framework="' +framework+ '"><img src="del.png"></a>' + '<a href="/frameworks/' +framework+'">' +framework+ '</a>';
```

This got me the desired result.

[image]